# Unclear reason for assignment discards volatile qualifier

Tags: c

I have a pointer field in a struct that points to a linked list of struct instances.

```
struct myStruct {
    some fields...
    struct list_objects * volatile list;
}
```

According to my understanding I declare it like that to tell the compiler the pointer can change from other threads, so don't cache it.
Not the content of what `list` points to will change but the pointer will change. (otherwise volatile must be the first keyword right?)

Access to `list` is protected with a mutex so threads don't collide writing to this pointer.

A problem occurs when I read this pointer's address into a pointer to pointer.

```
struct list_objects **ptrToPtr = &myStructVariable->list;
```

I need the double pointer to assign another pointer into this variable or to walk the linked list.

The compiler issues a "assignment discards volatile qualifier" warning. I read about this warning and think I basically understood it but I don't understand why it appears here.
The address of this variable should never change. The content is volatile, but not the place where this content resides.

I guess I have a bad understanding of this matter. Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: You just need `struct list_objects * volatile *`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry for the late response, didn't see this on the weekend. This was the first try, there was no other code around. The struct has some more but unimportant fields.

Comment: Are you sure you need volatile here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the `volatile` in this case is specific to the pointer and you should be able to do things like discarding the qualifier when copying the variable:

```
int* volatile vptr;
int* ptr = vptr;
```

Just as we can assign the value of a `const int` to an `int`.

However, that's not what your code does. It tries to point at the original type. For that you need a "pointer to volatile pointer to type". In your case this would be `struct list_objects *volatile * ptrToPt` (read right-to-left).

Alternatively, this would be fine too:

```
struct list_objects*  volatile vptr = ...;
struct list_objects*  ptr = vptr;
struct list_objects** pptr = &ptr;
```

But note that this take a copy of the original pointer, so if the original changes, then `ptr` will still contain the old address.

Comment: *so if the original changes, then ptr will still contain the old address.* yes this is ok. Code is protected with a mutex so during this piece of code the pointer won't change. The important thing is to really read the actual value once, not some cached value.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that `ptrToPtr` will not change (if you perform no assignment to it), so it does not need to be volatile. However, `*ptrToPtr` may change, because it is effectively `myStructVariable->list`.

So your declaration should be `struct list_objects * volatile * ptrToPtr = &myStructVariable->list;`.

Answer (score 1):

`&myStructVariable->list` is a pointer to a *volatile pointer* to `struct list_objects`.

So you need to declare `ptrToPtr` as

```
struct list_objects *volatile *ptrToPtr;
//                   ^^^^^^^^
```